# Trying to start a dialog after bool task, application stucks

Tags: c#, xamarin

When i'm using async task result inside bool button application is stuck

```
async Task<bool> task1()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int a = 0; a <= 1000000000; a++)
        {

        }
    });
    return true;
}

private  void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    setDialog(true);
    if (task1().Result==true)
      setDialog(false);
}

private void setDialog(bool show)
{

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.SetView(Resource.Layout.layout1);
    Dialog dialog = builder.Create();
    dialog.SetCancelable(false);
    if (show) dialog.Show();
    else dialog.Dismiss();
}
```

When i'm pressing start button click my application is stuck and doesnt let me do anything.
If i will use task inside button event then everything is going fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You deadlocked your application. This: `task1().Result` waits synchronously and defeats the purpose of tasks. Use async/await like this instead:

```
private async void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    setDialog(true);
    var result = await task1();
    if (result)
      setDialog(false);
}
```